# How to fix "Unexpected Token :" error when writing to a file in JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am currently working on a new discord bot for my server and I've just started utilising .js files to store permanent data. I have set up a system to log attendees of a raid by typing "[Finished]   etc... If the .js file where I am storing the data is empty everything works fine and all the data is correctly written to the file. However, if the bot restarts and then the .js file already contains data on other attendees and I attempt to write new data to that file it will throw me the "Unexpected Token" error.

I've attempted using fs.writeFileSync() but that doesn't seem to fix it, I've done a lot of research but can't seem to find a specific answer for my question.

Empty file to write to:

```
{

}
```

File when data is already there:

```
{
    "2887482348774": {
        "amount": 1
    },
    "1746782476348": {
        "amount": 1
    }
}
```

Fake discord IDs.

Command Code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const fs = require('fs');

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
  bot.msgs = require("./raiddata/raidattendance.js");
  if (message.channel.id !== '631620937418145802') return;
  if (!message.member.roles.some(r => ["Raider in Command", "Permissions"].includes(r.name))) return;

  for (let attenders of message.mentions.users.keyArray()) {
    message.channel.send(`Found user: ${attenders}`);
    bot.msgs [attenders] = {
      amount: 1
    }
    console.log("Works");
    fs.writeFileSync ('./commands/raiddata/raidattendance.js', JSON.stringify (bot.msgs, null, 4), err => {
      if (err) throw err;
    });
    message.channel.send(bot.msgs[attenders].amount);
  }
}

module.exports.config = {
  command: "finished]"
}
```

I expect the code to just continue to write to the file from where it left off but it doesn't. Here is the error I get:

```
8 commands found.
Command announcement.js loading...
Command changelog.js loading...
Command delete.js loading...
Command lock.js loading...
Command lograid.js loading...
Command notice.js loading...
Command raid.js loading...
Command unlock.js loading...
Bot is now running.
(node:6896) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: C:\Users\Removed\Downloads\Removed\Removed\commands\raiddata\raidattendance.js:2
    "1746782476348": {
                   ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:721:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
```

Comment: Either use fs.writeFile with a callback function as last argument or use fs.writeFileSync inside a try/catch.Using a callback with the sync versions of the fs API is guaranteed to not do what you need it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're using `require()` to read in a json file with `.js` extension. This is not expected. If you change the file to have a `.json` extension, it'll fix the issue.

You may want to read the file in using the `fs` module instead of using `require()` as it will give greater flexibility and probably better practice.

Comment: Thank you very much, that fixed it! I'll also try using the fs module as you've suggested.